# Sql function for statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I have table below:[image: tblBankTransaction TransID(PK,Auto)]

Now I need the table like:

[image: Table for statement]
Here:If TransType='Deposit' then it need in Debit and if TransType='Withdraw' then it need to be in Credit, And Debit-Credit from first to Last as Statement(Balance). Can you give any solution?
Please ask me for further clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The balance is a bit tricky.  The rest is a simple `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when TransType = 'Deposit' then amount end) as credit,
       (case when TransType = 'Withdraw' then amount end) as debit,
       sum(case when TransType = 'Deposit' then amount
                when TransType = 'Withdraw' then - amount
           end) over (partition by BankName order by TransDate
                     ) as balance
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I want. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am getting the question you need 2 queries with 'where' clause.
For exemple "Select BankName, TransDate, TransMiti, Description from TableName where TransType = "Deposit""
same goes for WithDraw.
Here is the link to to learn more.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp